# Is it a hindrance to wave your arms around at the net?

Tags: rules, tennis

I’ve seen someone do this repeatedly, and when I told him that in a league setting some might consider it a hindrance, he insisted it’s not a hindrance.

Answer (score 3):

Movements made solely to distract are certainly likely to be ruled hindrances.  From the [USTA Rules and Regulations](https://www.usta.com/content/dam/usta/pdfs/2015_Code.pdf):

> 35. Body movement. A player may feint with the body while a ball is in play. A player may change position at any time, including while the server is tossing a ball. Any other movement or any sound that is made solely to distract an opponent, including, but not limited to, waving arms or racket or stamping feet, is not allowed.

The player is allowed to make normal tennis movements, but waving at the opponent is definitely not a normal tennis movement.